# Combobox selected item WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have tried a code in which i am retrieving video names from folder. When i select some item from combobox it does not display the name in combobox selection. I go through all the stuff over stackoverflow. But none of it solved the issue. Any suggestions please.

**Code**

```
public partial class TextToSignWindow : Window
{
    public TextToSignWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var rootFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        var root = rootFolder + @"\Videos\";
        string localPath = new Uri(root).LocalPath;
        PopulateListBox(data,localPath, "*.wmv");
    }

    private void PopulateListBox(ComboBox cmb, string Folder, string FileType)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
            var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            cmb.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }

    private void data_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        data.SelectedValue =data.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

**WPF**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="data" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          FontFamily="verdana" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          FontSize="28" 
          Text="" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="81" 
          Margin="29,214,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="326" 
          SelectionChanged="data_SelectionChanged_1" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

Comment: Try this:  cmd.Items.add(new { FileName = name });  REMOVE: SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ADD: DisplayMemberPath="FileName" SelectedValuePath="FileName"

Comment: @Kris it passes an exception at `data.SelectedValue =data.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: dynamic selectedItem = data.SelectedItem;  data.SelectedValue = selectedItem.FileName;

Comment: @Kris still not displaying name is selected item

Comment: Strange it's working for me.  Are you getting a list of items in the ComboBox?

Comment: Also you shouldn't be doing this, why are you doing this? private void data_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.SelectedValue =data.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

Comment: When the SelectionChanged Event fires you shouldn't set the selected value to itself. dynamic selectedItem = data.SelectedItem;
            var SelectedValue = selectedItem.FileName;

Comment: Of course it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the DisplayMemberPath

```
<ComboBox x:Name="data" IsEditable="True" FontFamily="verdana" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  FontSize="28" Text=""  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="81" Margin="29,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="326" SelectionChanged="data_SelectionChanged_1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" DisplayMemberPath="NameOfFieldToDisplay"/>
```

You may also need to include the SelectedValuePath="NameOfSelectedValueField"

For example: Typically the DisplayMemberPath is your Description string, and the SelectedValuePath is your Id int.

Here's a copy paste from code i'm currently using:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxName" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" Width="300"  FontSize="14.667" SelectionChanged="comboBoxName_SelectionChanged">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a sample It worked

Xaml

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="data" IsEditable="True" FontFamily="verdana" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  FontSize="28" Text=""  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="81" Margin="29,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="326" SelectionChanged="data_SelectionChanged_1"  />
```

Code Behind

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.Items.Add("test");
            data.Items.Add("test1");
        }   

        private void data_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.SelectedValue = data.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont send your combobox to function

```
  private void PopulateListBox(string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
        var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
        data.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

And if you wanna send, try it by ref

```
 private void PopulateListBox(ref ComboBox cmb, string Folder, string FileType)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
            var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            cmb.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }
```